# ADF Mobile package import issue

Tags: java, import, package, oracle-adf-mobile

I am trying to import `RichSelectOneChoice` to my ADF mobile application's back end bean. I been trying to use the following package for import without luck. `oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichSelectOneChoice`
Should i be importing another package?